# From a Catholic perspective what does it mean for all creatures to fulfill God's will whether they know and want to or not?

Tags: catholicism, will-of-god, omnipotence, sovereignty

In the *Diary* of Saint Faustina, entry **(586)**, Our Lord says---

> **And know this, too, My daughter: all creatures, whether they know it or not, and whether they want to or not, always fulfill My will.**

I have gone through all 1828 entries of St. Faustina's *Diary* on multiple occasions and have found no contradictions (save one insignificant date). Therefore, I am convinced of its truth, albeit I am having difficulty understanding what the above quote means.

From a Catholic perspective, what might this mean? For clearly, God does not *will* the sinner's sin, but rather, permits it (for a greater good, I believe, known to Him. Perhaps this is an answer.)

Comment: _In whom also we have obtained an inheritance, being predestinated according to the purpose of him **who worketh all things after the counsel of his own will**:_ Ephesians 1:11 KJV.

Comment: @curiousdanni The title that you insist on giving to this post is misleading. I asked for an answer ``from a Catholic perspective,'' not ``according to Catholicism'' as you have insisted. It is possible that the Catholic Church has no formal teaching on the question I posed; thus I chose the phrasing of my question as I did. Finally, there is nothing greater than the Faith that Jesus Christ has given us. Thus, I respectfully reprove you for your tenacious insistence on your edits, which in my mind, has provided a  dis-service to say the least.

Comment: I don't think that's really a very meaningful difference, it's not like I edited the title to ask what the Catholic Catechism or Canon Law said. How's the title now? Feel free to edit it more, but please make it an actual question. "A question pertaining to ..." is not actually a question and we really prefer the title to be a real question.

Answer (score 2):

God is omnipotent. Nothing can hinder the fulfillment of His holy will.

St. Thomas Aquinas answers the question "Whether the will of God is always fulfilled?" ([*Summa Theologica* I q. 19 a. 6](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/FP/FP019.html#FPQ19A6THEP1) co.) by saying:

> The will of God must needs always be fulfilled. In proof of which we must consider that since an effect is conformed to the agent according to its form, the rule is the same with active causes as with formal causes. The rule in forms is this: that although a thing may fall short of any particular form, it cannot fall short of the universal form. For though a thing may fail to be, for example, a man or a living being, yet it cannot fail to be a being. Hence the same must happen in active causes. Something may fall outside the order of any particular active cause, but not outside the order of the universal cause; under which all particular causes are included: and if any particular cause fails of its effect, this is because of the hindrance of some other particular cause, which is included in the order of the universal cause. Therefore an effect cannot possibly escape the order of the universal cause. Even in corporeal things this is clearly seen. For it may happen that a star is hindered from producing its effects; yet whatever effect does result, in corporeal things, from this hindrance of a corporeal cause, must be referred through intermediate causes to the universal influence of the first heaven. Since, then, the will of God is the universal cause of all things, it is impossible that the divine will should not produce its effect. Hence that which seems to depart from the divine will in one order, returns into it in another order; as does the sinner, who by sin falls away from the divine will as much as lies in him, yet falls back into the order of that will, when by its justice he is punished.

Answer (score 0):

It is God's will that human beings may freely choose what they do. It is also God's will that good choices and bad choices have different eternal rewards.

Comment: Is this the Catholic perspective, or your own? Please [edit] this to add quotes or references to authoritative Catholic sources.